# Is $\zeta(-1)=0$ in the empty topological space?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, ring-theory, riemann-zeta

I have checked the  [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring)  properties I accrossed a nice property which states that The ring of continious real valued function is zero ring  in empty topological space , Now in the zero ring  we may assum that $1=0$ this mean that 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 0=0$ yield to $\zeta(-1)=0$ such that Riemann zeta function is extend by analytic continuation to be defined in the whole complex plane and continiuous ? Is this really true in empty topological space ?  probably I have a misunderstanding properties of zero ring

Comment: Are you working in the zero ring or in $\Bbb{C}$, since you use a fact about one to make a claim in the other.  If working in the zero ring, what is "$-1$" in "$\zeta(-1)$"?  It must be $0$, so the only value of $\zeta$ you can discuss in the zero ring is $\zeta(0)$...

Comment: "Analytic continuation" is a term applied to the complex plane, not the zero ring. There is no definition of how to take an element of the trivial ring to a generic complex number power; only integer powers like $n^1$ make sense. @EricTowers I don't think it makes sense to exponentiate an element of the trivial ring, so presumably $\zeta$'s inputs are still natural numbers. (Although the whole exercise is still pointless since every trivial-ring-valued function is constant and captures nothing about zeta functions...)

Comment: Also, infinite sums really only make sense if there's a topology. You luck out with the trivial ring's discrete topology; any other finite ring's discrete topology would only allow infinite sums to exist if the summands are eventually all $0$ (i.e. the sum is essentially finite).

Answer (score 3):

The point is that there only exists one function $\emptyset \rightarrow A$ for any set $A$, namely the empty function. If now $A$ happens to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ (or any other topological space), then this single function is continuous and as the set of continuous function from a topological space to the reals forms a ring, it is isomorphic to the zero ring (any ring with one element is isomorphic to the zero ring). There is no way to talk about any other function including the Riemann zeta function here though. These elements do not lie in that ring.